# Formula Field to get most current year from 3 fields

Tags: formula, formula-field, conditional

I have 3 different fields that track year in the form of text (4 characters). I'm trying to create a new formula field that would give me the latest year out of all 3 fields.

For example: field1= 1999, field2=2002, field3=2011, the formula should return value 2011. All fields are text right now so it might need to be converted.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Max(Value(Field1), Value(Field2), Value(Field3))
```

Max returns the largest value of its parameters, Value converts text to numbers.

Edit: The previous function only works if all three fields are numbers and populated. If this won't always be true, use the following version:

```
Max( 
  If(IsNumber(Field1__c), Value(Field1__c), 0), 
  If(IsNumber(Field2__c), Value(Field2__c), 0), 
  If(IsNumber(Field3__c), Value(Field3__c), 0)
)
```

This one will always show a value even if one or more fields are empty.

Comment: This formula makes perfect sense and no errors show with "Check Syntax". However the field stays empty for whatever reason. Any ideas what could be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: @user1781482 You had some blank values present. I've provided an updated function that ignores blank values.